Stakeholder Bottleneck
I've been facing a rather silly yet challenging stakeholder bottleneck in my role as a PM. My internal stakeholders/customers are pushing me to block their calendars 3-4 weeks out with anticipated meetings, when in reality I do not have any agreed recurring/one-off meeting cadence in place. However I managed to just block hours on their calendars but now they are complaining that they do not have enough time during the day to actually do the work.
Once we had a few of the agreed meetings squared away, I cleared up the rest of the calendars and put in slots for doing the actual work. It seems like no matter what I do, they have something to complain about. I feel like I'm losing respect by dancing to their tunes, however I do not have a reason not to listen to their requirements as a PM.
The hardest part to realize is that a new vendor PM started and since the company is paying them they wanted scheduling to be handled by the new person. She blocked meetings far out but surprisingly she was not asked to book additional hours to do the work. I'm starting to take this personally. How do you normally handle these kind of situations as a PM? Is this an experience thing or lack of assertiveness?
Any help here is appreciated.

Question - who is the person being held accountable if things arent done in a timely manner

Thank you everyone for chiming in. All the answers are really helpful. As far as manager support go , my manager is pushing for these steps as well along with my stakeholders. My stakeholders are finance folks (very task oriented) and the business sponsor of the project(finance lead) is the one who is pushing for all these spoon feeding from me. My team mates are supportive and they think she is trying to weasel her way out of doing anything. I want to believe this is an uncommon scenario but regardless I'm in this mess.

So they stack holders requested meetings and now that you scheduled meetings they are saying what exactly? Your question is confusing as it’s not clear if you’re responsible for these stack holders as say their manager or what part you actually play. You mentioned another PM, why?


However I managed to just block hours on their calendars but now they are complaining that they do not have enough time during the day to actually do the work.

Reach an agreement with how many hours they can afford. If that number is too low for you, you need to go to your manager, and see what can be done to give your stakeholders more bandwidth.
It is pointless spending your time juggling things, in order to arrange X hours of meetings, if that number is insufficient for your requirements, or doesn't work for them.
By getting a number up-front, you don't give them a leg to stand on.
Also, you should consider if there are other ways that information can be shared rather than meetings.

There sems to be a misunderstanding that you should be managing people's workdays.  If people don't have enough time to get their work done that is between them and their manager.  They just inform you that they are missing their deadlines.  If resourcing is insufficient, management needs to adjust resourcing.  It isn't up to the PM to manage workload except for assigned tasks and expected completion.  You aren't their boss, your role is to manage the schedule.   People mange their own workday.
I feel like the team is messing with you and trying to skate out of work by looking busy vi having full calendars.  Please don't schedule meetings that aren't necessary to meet their false needs.  Maybe the way you are defining customers and stakeholders is the problem.  Stakeholders and customers get project output.  Resources do the work.  Sure they are kind of a customer of PMO, but you are also their customer.  Certainly don't treat project resources like customers in a "the customer is always right" kind of way.  They are workers, not buyers of your product, and they supply the labor to get the job done.

Meetings are not the purpose of their job. You also do not need to book time in the calendar to do work - time is by default for doing work. The calendar is for meetings - i.e., interrupting work. To organize their work, you use the task tracking tool (hopefully you have one).
Here are my thoughts on your issue, in the order they came to my mind.
So you need to do PM work in the first place: WBS, tasks, assign tasks, get agreement (from the team) of completion in time and with proper quality, monitor progress, receive work products. If the quality and / or the deadlines are not met, you clarify the causes. If they are not satisfactory, escalate to their managers.
Another thing you can try is to get some advice / support from your manager. Either he tells you some important info you do not yet have, to help you make progress, or he can have a chat with the manager of the team to work out a solution. As I see it, you are unlikely to be able to fix it alone.
Also: instead of seeing the team as "enemies", try to "befriend" them. Have chats with them, one by one, try to understand what causes them to behave like that. Ask them for advice: how they expect you to organize things, so they can work happily and deliver the proper quality on time.
The most important: keep a very open mind. Do not assume that things can be done in only one way. You would be surprised how many very different ways can lead to the "same" result.
Being a PM is about working with people, not with the calendar. You might need some training(s) in that area.


My internal stakeholders/customers are pushing me to block their calendars 3-4 weeks out with anticipated meetings, when in reality I do not have any agreed recurring/one-off meeting cadence in place.

If you do not need, do not do it. They are messing with you big time. You need to organize the meetings (with the team) only for tracking the status of the work. And that is usually 1 hour per week in traditional projects, max 2 (you did not mention stand-up, so I assume the project is not Agile, which uses 15 min every morning). If they have any problems, they have to organize meetings with you or with whoever. If they cannot do the work, THEY have to escalate to you or to their managers.
You definitely need trainings and support from your manager (and possibly their manager(s) ).


However I managed to just block hours on their calendars but now they are complaining that they do not have enough time during the day to actually do the work.

That's because you did something you should not have done. Delete all the meetings that you do not need. Emergencies are not solved with recurrent, regular meetings, because you do not plan to have regular emergencies. Empty their calendars, let them do their work. Escalate when they don't.


I cleared up the rest of the calendars and put in slots for doing the actual work.

You use a task tracker for assigning work, not the calendar.

If they have family or friends in management, just go find another job, you will never fix anything - except ruin your health and possibly your life.

"Meetings are not the purpose of your job. You also do not need to book time in the calendar to do work - time is by default for doing work." Bold claim. Booking meetings with people who are in high demand is a simple reality that some people have to deal with.

@GregoryCurrie: I have the feeling that you downvoted without reading my answer: "The calendar is for meetings - i.e., interrupting work." And you said: "Booking meetings ... is a simple reality" Where is the conflict? Also: working and talking about work are not the same thing. Making decisions is just that, making decisions. The actual work is done outside meetings - and the time for working is not in the calendar - but in a task tracking tool - hopefully they have such tool.

@GregoryCurrie: And I noticed a small mistake, I updated the answer :)

"You also do not need to book time in the calendar to do work - time is by default for doing work." - I disagree as well. In Outlook or other meeting assistants, a time where you don't have a meeting scheduled is time that's shown as free to throw a meeting in - a lot of the time I needed to book a slot with myself just to prevent people from throwing in last minute meetings when I had some specific work to do.

Yes, that is a problem, not a rule. Unfortunately, people do not care when someone really needs to concentrate on work, and forces meeting after meetings after meetings... Just because the calendar is empty. I even have the experience when the meetings are organized especially during lunch break - just because the calendar is free. And if you add a meeting there, people still invite you to meetings, because they know that people book fake meetings, hoping to have some lunch... I only mentioned what should be, not the reality - unfortunately...
